# X.509 certificate cannot be installed from Android Instant App?

Tags: java, android, ca, android-instant-apps

I am working on an app that downloads X.509 certificate from our server and starts the default Android system installer that installs it using [KeyChain.createInstallIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html#createInstallIntent()).

```
Intent intent = KeyChain.createInstallIntent();
byte[] p12 = readFile("keystore-test.pfx");
intent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_PKCS12, p12);
startActivity(intent);
```

This works fine in standard (installable) version of app, but in **Instant app** , I get this error message :

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.certinstaller/com.android.certinstaller.CertInstallerMain}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

So, it seems that CertInstaller Activity cannot be started from Instant app? I hope someone can point out my mistake, or maybe knows some way around this limitation.

Comment: My guess is that this is intentional, as a security precaution.

Comment: I seems so, do you maybe have an idea of a way around this, or it's impossible to install CA certificate from Instant apps?

Comment: I would be concerned if an Instant App could request to install a CA certificate. However, I do not work with Instant Apps much, and so I do not know if there is a workaround.

Comment: With refrence to https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/CertInstaller/+/88ded90/src/com/android/certinstaller/CertInstallerMain.java to install certificate it required `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`  but as of now it not supported, can you check more details here https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/prepare.html. I hope it help to understand the problems.

Comment: I hope your problem has been solve or Can you file a bug to Google, then link to it back in here? It would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Comment: It hasn't been solved and I don't believe it can be done from Instant app, so I am now opening it via Chrome browser. I am starting it with Intent that contains our server URL and it then downloads the certificate and offers to install it. I filed a bug to Google, but I expect them only to answer that it's like that intentionally. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77432858